# The parameters 'project' for goal ... are missing or invalid

Tags: maven

Say you have plugin, that you configured in you pom like this:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.vbmacher</groupId>
        <artifactId>cup-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And when you build you get this error:

```
$ mvn compile
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.vbmacher:cup-maven-plugin:1.0.1:generate (default) on project jac-core: The parameters 'project' for goal com.github.vbmacher:cup-maven-plugin:1.0.1:generate are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

And you don't understand because you are running inside of a project !

Comment: The parameter `project` is missing in the configuration of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The project of the plugins Mojo was declared like this :

```
/**
 * @parameter property="project"
 * @required
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

Which is apparently wrong and does not use your project to populate the Mojo. So I changed it to the following:

```
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project}"
 * @required
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

And it now goes well :-)

Comment: Don't use XDoclet anymore...Better use [annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html).

Comment: The plugin is not mine and uses Xdoxclet. I was afraid to mix both.

Answer (score -1):

Well the answer if that you need to put the <plugin> declaration inside of a <pluginManagement> in your pom :

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.vbmacher</groupId>
        <artifactId>cup-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: This will not change the usage of a parameter which is the cause of the error message.

Comment: I've just realized that. But shouldn't it default to the pom's project its declared in ?

Comment: It turns out that the plugin I used was at afault, at least for my version of Maven (3.0.5). See my other answer for more details.